# How to move MobyLinuxVM.vhdx to another drive

Tags: windows, docker, memory

I use Docker on Windows 10. After running `docker pull kaggle/python` the file MobyLinuxVM.vhdx goes up to nearly 30 GB and makes my C drive full. How can I safely move this file to another drive?

Answer (score 2):

1 - Shut down Docker

2 - Move the `C:\path\to\file\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx` to `E:\Foo\Bar\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx` (the bigger Driver)

3 - Edit `%APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json` to set `"MobyVhdPathOverride": "E:\\Foo\\Bar\\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx"`

4 - Start Docker

For the next time if you want to edit the VM Default location when running pull command, open powershell as administrator and run this command :

`Set-VMHost -VirtualHardDiskPath <the/new/path>`

to check if you changed the path run this command :

`(get-vmhost).VirtualHardDiskPath`

Comment: How to do it in the latest version? As I don't have the MobyVhdPathOverride setting in the settings.json now.

Answer (score 1):

Just editing the `settings.json` did not work for me.

I also do step 1 and 2:

> 1 - Shut down Docker
>
> 2 - Move the C:\path\to\file\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx to E:\Foo\Bar\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx (the bigger Driver)

But after that I started the Hyper-V-Manager and opened the hyper-v settings on the actions panel. There I changed `C:\path\to\file\` to `E:\Foo\Bar\`.

I am not sure, but I think this is equal to the mentioned powershell commands.

After starting Docker for Desktop the new location is visible in the advanced settings of the docker settings dialog.

**Hint**: you can also use the Hyper-V settings to inspect the path where you can find the `MobyLinuxVM.vhdx`.

**Second Hint**: If you have more than the `MobyLinuxVM.vhdx` in the `C:\path\to\file\` folder, you have to copy them all the new location. Otherwise they are not reachable by the Hyper-V Manager.